# How can I apply ceiling on a dataframe column?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, rounding

I have a dataframe with a numeric series, example below. How can I ceil every value, with a step of let's say  0.2? It is very easy in Excel, via `=CEILING(x, 0.2)` but what about Python?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1.3, 1.5, 1,6, 1.7, 2]})
```

Comment: See [ask] and provide [mcve]

Comment: Anyway, `df['column_name'].apply(lambda n: round(n, 2))` may or may not do what you want.

Comment: @apostolos, does this solve your problem? if so, consider accepting an answer (green tick on left), so other users know.

Answer (score 5):

To my knowledge, such a function does not exist natively.

You can use NumPy (credit to @DSM):

```
step = 0.2
df['B'] = np.ceil((df['A'].values / step)) * step
```

A less performant version via `pd.Series.apply`:

```
import pandas as pd
import math

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1.3, 1.5, 1,6, 1.7, 2]})

def ceil(x, step=1):
    return step * math.ceil(x/step)

df['B'] = df['A'].apply(ceil, step=0.2)

#      A    B
# 0  1.0  1.0
# 1  1.3  1.4
# 2  1.5  1.6
# 3  1.0  1.0
# 4  6.0  6.0
# 5  1.7  1.8
# 6  2.0  2.0
```

Comment: Using `apply` will be considerably slower than a vectorized approach like `np.ceil((df/step))*step`, though, right?